# Errors using pointers with Function in C

Tags: c, string, pointers, compiler-errors

First of all I apologize, this is probably a simple question but I'm not very well versed in any coding. For this code, I need to use pointer syntax and define my own function to reverse a string. I'm not allowed to use strlen() in this situation. I've tried playing around with the pointers, but I always get the following errors:

```
incompatible type when assigning to type char[15] from type char
```

(I have to write this in pico, so I'm not exactly sure what line number it refers to. It  appears to be somewhere around the point I call the `strcmp()` function

```
assignment makes integer from pointer without cast
```

(This one appears to be when I define the s pointer in the function or around there)

Any and all help/troubleshooting ideas would be much appreciated. I'm using a gcc  compiler, if that matters

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

char revcheck(char String[15]);

int main(void)
{
    char String[15];

    printf("Enter a string: \n");
    scanf(" %s", String);

    if (strcmp(String, "ENGR-awesome"))
    {
        printf("That's Right!");
    }
    else
    {
        String = revcheck(String);
    }

    return 0;
}

char revcheck(char String[15])
{
    char Letter, *end, *s;
    end = strchr(String, '\0');
    s = String;
    while (end > s)
        Letter = &end;
    *end = *s;
    *s = Letter;
    end--;
    s++;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Another thing, `Letter = &end;` `letter` is a `char` and `end` is a `char*`, `&end` is a `char**`, so you are assigning `char**` to a `char`.

Comment: You must set up your development tools, so that you will see all information output by compiler. There is no any sense to guess on which line there are errors. Use proper IDE for that.

Comment: It's not clear where you're copying the string to; in fact, I don't see any copying going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `revcheck()` returns a `char`. You are trying to assign that to a `char[]`.

You should have your `revcheck()` return a `char*`:

```
char* revcheck(char String[15]);
```

Comment: You can't assign a `char *` to a `char []` either.  You could `strcpy()` the return value into the array: `strcpy(String, revcheck(String));`, but you can't assign to arrays.

Comment: Ok. I tried adding the asterisk in the function prototype and declaration. No good, I'm still getting the same error. Are there any other places I'd have to add one? I believe the compiler is telling me the error is on the line where I say s = String.

Comment: @user3400424 did you use `strcpy` instead of assignment as @JonathanLeffler suggested? you should.

Answer (score 0):

First you should bear in mind that C-string is an **array** of chars, and can be represented as **char***, a pointer to this array. So, revcheck should not return char. This is the string where the compiler gives the error:

```
String = revcheck(String);
```

revcheck can reverse the string in the String array itself (in place) without returning anything. (You can count the len yourself and then swap elements.)